# mysql группировка данных в строку или перекрестный запрос

Tags: mysql

Постарался максимально упростить. Есть четыре таблицы с данными о походе на рыбалку (два справочника и две - про рыбалки и улов в каждой):

```
fish        |   river       |   expedition      |   expedition_catch
id  name    |   id  name    |   id  river_id    |   expedition_id   fish_id fish_count
1   Окунь   |   1   Ока     |   1   1           |   1               1       5
2   Щука    |   2   Енисей  |   2   1           |   1               2       3
3   Голавль |               |   3   2           |   2               3       4
            |               |                   |   3               1       6
            |               |                   |   3               2       3
            |               |                   |   3               1       4
```

В `expedition` - номер похода и река, а в `expedition_catch` - информация о том, какие рыбы пойманы и сколько.

Нужно вывести данные так: сгруппировать все походы по рекам и показать, сколько рыб каждого вида поймано для одной реки. Вот в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой вывод получается с помощью этого запроса:

```
SELECT r.name,
SUM(if(f.name = 'Окунь',ec.fish_count, 0)) as 'Окунь',
SUM(if(f.name = 'Щука',ec.fish_count, 0)) as 'Щука',
SUM(if(f.name = 'Голавль',ec.fish_count, 0)) as 'Голавль'
FROM expedition e
JOIN river r ON r.id = e.river_id
JOIN expedition_catch ec ON e.id = ec.expedition_id
JOIN fish f ON ec.fish_id = f.id
GROUP BY e.river_id
```

Недостаток этого запроса: если добавится еще вид рыбы, жерех к примеру, запрос придется переделывать. То есть он бестолковый получается - приходится в запросе вручную рыб перечислять. Подскажите, можно ли средствами Mysql написать запрос так, чтобы он сам "смотрел" всех рыб и выводил их суммы в строку?

Я понимаю, что можно сделать проще и получить данные так:

```
SELECT r.name, f.name, SUM(ec.fish_count) as fishcount
FROM expedition e
JOIN river r ON r.id = e.river_id
JOIN expedition_catch ec ON e.id = ec.expedition_id
JOIN fish f ON ec.fish_id = f.id
GROUP BY e.river_id, ec.fish_id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И затем, средствами php формировать таблицу. Но все-таки интересно, можно ли сразу получить данные в нужном формате.

Спасибо!

Comment: *Подскажите, можно ли средствами Mysql написать запрос так, чтобы он сам "смотрел" всех рыб и выводил их суммы в строку?* Запрос - нет. Процедуру - можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Предупреждение**: никогда не делайте этого в реальных проектах.

Подсказка вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql) (eng).

Суть примерно в том, что чисто запросом Вы не можете выбрать динамическое количество полей, но Вы можете сам запрос склеить средствами mysql.

Итого Ваш конкретный запрос будет составляться так:

```
SET @a = CONCAT(
    'SELECT r.name,\n',
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SUM(if(f.name = \'',name,'\', ec.fish_count, 0)) as \'',name,'\'\n') FROM fish),
    'FROM expedition e
    JOIN river r ON r.id = e.river_id
    JOIN expedition_catch ec ON e.id = ec.expedition_id
    JOIN fish f ON ec.fish_id = f.id
GROUP BY e.river_id;'
);
PREPARE stmt FROM @a;
EXECUTE @a;
```

Первым запросом записываем в переменную собственно будущий запрос, вторым - "подготавливаем" его, третьим - исполняем.

К слову, используя PDO Вы могли бы сделать вообще вот так:

```
/** @var PDO $db */
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT r.name, f.name, SUM(ec.fish_count) as fishcount
FROM expedition e
JOIN river r ON r.id = e.river_id
JOIN expedition_catch ec ON e.id = ec.expedition_id
JOIN fish f ON ec.fish_id = f.id
GROUP BY e.river_id, ec.fish_id');

$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

и совершенно **бесплатно** получить массив вида:

```
$data = [
    'Ока' => [
        ['name' => 'Окунь', 'fishcount' => 5],
        ['name' => 'Щука', 'fishcount' => 3],
        ['name' => 'Голавль', 'fishcount' => 4]
    ],
    'Енисей' => [
        ['name' => 'Окунь', 'fishcount' => 10],
        ['name' => 'Щука', 'fishcount' => 3],
    ]
];
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться!